# Fluke in integration means taking out an additive constant is OK?

Tags: integration, constants

I'm trying to do this question below, which is from an A Level textbook book.

[image]

I've said that the area enclosed by the curve, the $y-$axis, $y=2$ and $y=3$ is given by

\begin{equation}
\int_{2}^{3} x \, dy = \int_{2}^{3} (y^2 - 2) \, dy
\end{equation}

and so to get the area $CDE$ I just need to take off the area of the rectangle enclosed by the lines $DE$, the $y-$axis, $y=2$, and $y=3$. The area of the rectangle is 2, and so my final answer for the area of $CDE$ is

\begin{equation}
\int_{2}^{3} (y^2 - 2) \, dy - 2.
\end{equation}

Comparing my answer to their answer, it looks as if they have taken the $-2$ inside the integral, which I thought was odd. Sanity check: you can't just take **additive** constants in/ out an integral can you?

So, curiosity then lead me to investigate when you **can** take an additive constant in or out of an integral, and I found the following:

[image]

It looks like that *when the limits of integration differ by 1, you can take in/out an additive constant*.

This result does neither seem obvious or intuitive. If some disagrees, please could they enlighten me?

Do people therefore think 6(iii) is a reasonable question? Or, do you think it is possibly an overlooked typo?

@Flame Trap

Ah, so the area is actually

\begin{equation}
\int_{2}^{3} (y^2 - 2) \, dy - \int_{2}^{3} 2 \, dy
\end{equation}

Got it!

Comment: The area is the difference between the curve and the line x=2

Comment: If $b=a+1$, then $\int_a^bc\,dx=c$. This says the area of a rectangle of base 1 and height $c$ is $c$, which seems pretty obvious to me.